# Is it possible to use only a few Wagtail modules in a Django project?

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to know if it is possible to only use some parts of the wagtail in a Django Project.

I want to just use StreamField to use some blocks and upload images, but from what I've researched, it's not possible to use the wagtail out of the packet, so I wonder if it really is not possible to use its modules outside of a wagtail project.

I want to do this because I want to "rebuild the wheel" because I'm still a beginner and doing it helps to learn, but I do not want to do that much like creating my own StreamField and my blocks, -end, which I do not have at the moment (not JS only).

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to use a few elements here and there, but they haven't been designed this way. Taking StreamField as an example, the model field might be functional but the form field is meant to be used within the context of the Wagtail admin.

There has already been some work done to decouple some elements and this is definitely a direction the core team wants to explore further but it isn't there yet and isn't the main focus at the moment.

The only element I can think of reusing outside of the Wagtail world is the RichText editor. It is based of [Draftail](https://www.draftail.org/) which you can use in your own project (although you'll have to create your own Django model/form fields).